# Semicolon for question-answer sentences?

Tags: semicolons

Semicolons are used to connect two independent clauses. Does it make sense to use it in a question-answer type sentence, like the following?

> Where is the milk; *there* is the milk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question is normally answered by another speaker, so of course the answer has to be a new sentence. Even if the first speaker is answering their own question, it makes sense to start a new sentence, especially since a question should end with a question mark.

> Where's the milk? Oh, *there* it is.

Comment: Yes, and questions get question marks, which tend to end the sentence. So ...